# Unable to log in with your OpenID provider: no OpenID identifier was provided

Tags: support, openid, login

I'm getting the following error when I attempt to log in using my OpenID provider:

> ### Unable to log in with your OpenID provider:
>
> ### no OpenID identifier was provided.

I run an old PHP OpenID script which I know hasn't changed recently.

**Has Stack Overflow changed their implementation, and if so what are the new requirements, or to what version of OpenID does it adhere?**

I'm looking at it from a few other angles - perhaps my webhost made some changes without notifying me of them, but I want to make sure it wasn't a change on SO's side as well.

Comment: Who's your provider? There were (are?) issues with Wordpress.

Comment: @ChrisF I am my own provider.

Comment: Of course - it's obvious now I re-read the question. Sorry.

Comment: @ChrisF No problem.

Comment: I'm suspicious of the "we have not changed anything for a while" SO response -- my PHP OpenID script stopped working around the same time, I filed a bug separately [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82085/unhelpful-openid-error-message)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out my hosting provider changed something that modified PHP's header settings.  Perhaps it was a regular php update with new security defaults, perhaps something else.

Regardless, the fix was to install a rewrite rule in .htaccess in the same directory as the phpmyid script:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} !^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} openid.mode=authorize
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !auth=
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} =GET
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING}&auth=%{HTTP:Authorization} [L]
```

If you have command line access, the following commands will create the file for you:

```
echo 'RewriteEngine on' >> .htaccess
echo 'RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} !^$' >> .htaccess
echo 'RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} openid.mode=authorize' >> .htaccess
echo 'RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !auth=' >> .htaccess
echo 'RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} =GET' >> .htaccess
echo 'RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING}&auth=%{HTTP:Authorization} [L]' >> .htaccess
```

I found my answer here, http://mikewest.org/2007/01/setting-up-an-openid-server-with-phpmyid , as it turns out that the error I was getting was actually "Missing expected authorization header."

Answer (score 1):

No, we have not changed anything for a while on that.

Also, you can use your alternative google profile URL to log in as well, which seems to be attached to your accounts, at least the ones I saw.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  I keep the google profile around in case something like this happens, but all signs seem to point toward a problem with my webhost.