# Unhelpful OpenID error message

Tags: support, openid, error-message

My OpenID provider is a copy of [phpMyId](http://siege.org/projects/phpMyID/) running on my server that I fiddled with a bit. Sometime in the last few weeks something changed so that the script doesn't work anymore -- I get the "Oops! Something Bad Happened" page when I try to login. I've never gotten that before; when I messed up the script I would end up back on the login page with an OpenID error instead. What changed with OpenID handling in the last few weeks? How can I debug the problem; is there a way to get an error message more specific than "Something bad happened"?

Comment: This triggered another openid "Really?" moment for me.  Why this just isn't built into my browser is beyond me.

Answer (score 3):

Recent changes in PHP seem to be the culprit, the problem is that phpmyid no longer sends the header correctly.  A rewrite rule, which I posted to my similar question, may solve your problem:

[Unable to log in with your OpenID provider: no OpenID identifier was provided](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79275/unable-to-log-in-with-your-openid-provider-no-openid-identifier-was-provided/82346#82346)

Answer (score 2):

Nothing changed on our end, but something changed on your end.

You can view source on the error page to get a tiny bit more detail. I don't see anything in our error logs.

Comment: Oh, that's handy. I don't suppose "An item with the same key has already been added." means anything? I haven't touched that script since I got it working months ago, but I'll fiddle later today to see if I caused it somehow