# Cannot login to Stack Overflow with OpenID

Tags: support, login, openid

I'm logged into Stack Overflow on other machines, yet my laptop I repeatedly get:

```
No openid identifier was provided
```

I use the same ID on other machines and other sites and they all work fine, yet not on Stack Overflow?

Comment: I'm not sure if it'd actually help, but have you tried the standard troubleshooting steps, like deleting temporary stuff on the machine?

Comment: What OpenID provider are you using? In case you're using your own provider it's dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79275/unable-to-log-in-with-your-openid-provider-no-openid-identifier-was-provided

Comment: I'm using Wordpress.

Comment: So it's most likely a problem on their side, not Stack Exchange. Try adding another provider which is more stable.

Comment: I don't have any other provider. Also, I can join Stack Exchange but not login to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Still, most likely a  problem on Wordpress side. You can register new account with Stack Exchange OpenID then add it as new login, this should also "fix" this issue.